# Access variable in JSON with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, solr

I'm having difficulty accessing a variable returned from solr in JSON format.  I'm using JQuery.

My JSON response looks like this

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":44,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"title:\"clrfying clan\" OR title:clrfying clan OR text:\"clrfying clan\" OR text:clrfying clan",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "clrfying",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":7,
        "endOffset":15,
        "suggestion":["clarifying"]},
      "clan",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":16,
        "endOffset":20,
        "suggestion":["clean"]},
      "clrfying",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":31,
        "endOffset":39,
        "suggestion":["clarifying"]},
      "clan",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":40,
        "endOffset":44,
        "suggestion":["clean"]},
      "clrfying",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":54,
        "endOffset":62,
        "suggestion":["clarifying"]},
      "clan",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":63,
        "endOffset":67,
        "suggestion":["clean"]},
      "clrfying",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":77,
        "endOffset":85,
        "suggestion":["clarifying"]},
      "clan",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":86,
        "endOffset":90,
        "suggestion":["clean"]},
      "collation",[
        "collationQuery","title:\"clarifying clean\" OR title:clarifying clean OR text:\"clarifying clean\" OR text:clarifying clean",
        "hits",44,
        "misspellingsAndCorrections",[
          "clrfying","clarifying",
          "clan","clean",
          "clrfying","clarifying",
          "clan","clean",
          "clrfying","clarifying",
          "clan","clean",
          "clrfying","clarifying",
          "clan","clean"]]]}}
```

The part I want to access is

```
"collation",[
            "collationQuery","title:\"clarifying clean\" OR title:clarifying clean OR text:\"clarifying clean\" OR text:clarifying clean",
```

I can't seem to access it though. I get this response using JQuery with the following code

```
$.getJSON("http://mydomain.com/solrsearch?q=title%3A%22clrfying%20clan%22+OR+title%3Aclrfying%20clan+OR+text%3A%22clrfying%20clan%22+OR+text%3Aclrfying%20clan&wt=json&indent=true", function(resp){})
```

I have tried to access collationQuery like this resp.spellcheck.suggestions.collation.collationQuery but I think I must be doing it incorrectly because it returns empty.

Comment: json structure is strange. `collation` isn't an object, it is an element of `suggestions` array that contains the string `"collation"`. Next element in `suggestsions` array after `"collation"` is an array containing data you want. Are you generating this data? Will be very difficult to use in this structure

Comment: No, I'm not generating this data, it's outputted by a program called 'solr'.  I thought it looked strange too, I wonder if it's a bug.  Even so, is there anyway I could access it in it's current state?

Comment: Is definitely a bug somewhere, going to require deep parsing of array indexes to find anything

Comment: var suggestions=res.spellcheck.suggestions;
var collation= suggestions[17];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way data is structured you will need to get index of `"collation"` in `suggestions` array, then get the array that is the next index and access 2nd element of that array.

It sure looks like intent of output was to use objects but output structure is flawed

```
var suggestions=resp.spellcheck.suggestions;

var colQuery= suggestions[ suggestions.indexOf('collation') +1][1];
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PnPf2/)**</kbd>

Even once found the result is poorly structured and will have to do some string parsing to get useable data from it

Comment: Amazing! Does the trick for now.  Hopefully SOLR will release a fix for this soon.

Comment: I would submit as a bug...this is very difficult to work with. Beware also when they patch it